# USB Gaming mouse not working on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, usb, windows-8.1, mouse

I recently bought a new Laptop. HP, Windows 10. I used my Gaming mouse DragonWar Thor ELE-G9 with my previous Windows 8.1 Laptop. Now the mouse has some plug problem and only works on 1 port on my old laptop. Now when I try connecting it to the new laptop, it doesn't work. I tried wiggling the cable (which used to work on my old laptop) but that didn't help as well. All the USB ports on my new laptop are working (of course they are, it a new computer after all), I've tried connecting different peripherals to the new laptop and they work fine, its just the mouse. I've even tried the updated DragonWar driver for my mouse, but no result.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Time to buy a new mouse?

Comment: As @DavidPostill says. Sounds like the bios of the mouse has problems. You may be able to hook up another similar mouse (same brand and type) to a usb port, and your old mouse may work on that port until it completely dies. But you are probably better of buying a new mouse anyway.

Comment: @LPChip any way of resetting the bios of the mouse or something? Maybe I could reset its firmware or something?? I can't really buy a new mouse at the moment..

Comment: I doubt it. A mouse is not usually a device for which you can easily flash its bios.

Comment: @LPChip is there no hope for me then?

Comment: For your current mouse? I don't think so.

Comment: @LPChip miracle, I connected my mouse to the pc and started playing assassins creed. After about an hour or so, all of a sudden the mouse automatically starts working! I tried rebooting and the mouse didn't light up until when the desktop came, and then as soon as I moved the mouse it started working again. I haven't tested it out much as I have to go for some work. But I'll come back and test it again. Can you suggest some test as well?

Comment: @YaddyVirus there aren't really any tests, besides... it works, don't break it. ;)

Comment: @LPChip Well it works, or it was working. I came back home, rebooted and the mouse isn't working again. All I can do is to wiggle cables/plug and reconnect. BIOS problems?

Comment: @YaddyVirus your mouse is having a hard time getting past the initialization stage. It will work eventually, if you're lucky.

Comment: @LPChip well after about a 100 reconnections it probably is working. Or maybe only for this time, I'll leave it connected for long, I won't shutdown the PC while using the mouse extensively... maybe that can help.